# Apache Common IO Create Directory on Linux

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, apache-commons, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a plugin for elasticsearch. In my plugin I'm using apache common for creating nested directory. I'm running my elasticsearch on Linux and when I try to use plugin. It throws an error "IOEXCEPTION : cannot create directory ....". Is there a solution for that? Do I need to set permissions for plugin? Btw I'm running elasticsearch as a service on my Linux system. Thanks for helps.

Comment: You do not need to use Commons IO to create directories. You can use [File.mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29). But it seems you have no permission to create directories. Could you create directories from linux shell? I think it is about permission of the `elasticsearch` user.

Comment: I've solved the creating directory problem. Thanks for the help. Now I'm having another issue :)